# How to do error management in a web development team?

Tags: agile, error-handling

What are some good practices to do error management in a web application of about 30 people divided into 5 people team, where each team is responsible of a specific part of the application?

I am looking for answers on:

- How do you make sure that new errors get addressed or triaged?
- How do you make sure that current errors get addressed/triaged or cleaned up? Assuming there are already a bunch of non addressed errors
- Do you prioritize the errors, or you try to mantain an address error ASAP mentality?

Comment: Your best bet is to treat each specific part of the application as a separate agile project and let those teams deal with the bugs related to their area. You can use an issue tracking software and let the teams prioritize and take on issues in their sprint plans.

Answer (score 1):

If by error you mean defect, a mistake in the code that needs to be corrected by a programmer, then what you need is a trouble ticket system.

This can be an elaborate piece of software or it can be a whiteboard.  Ether way you document the problem, prioritize it, and track it's resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you define clearly to the team what a 'bug' (/error/issue/defect) is and what it is not. For example, a bug may:

- **BE** A deviation in behaviour/appearance from a previously completed feature/story once deployed to production.
- **NOT BE** Something a product owner, stakeholder or user doesn't like or a suggestion for a change in behaviour.

This is pretty critical as you want to minimise bugs in your backlog given that they usually don't add new value to the product (value should have been added when the bug-free feature was completed initially).

So given our "bug" above:

- Get a bug tracking list/backlog visible somewhere so the product owner can prioritise it and the team and work from it. Use a whiteboard, post its or some software like [Trello](https://trello.com).
- Perhaps a senior technical team member or two can be responsible for triaging each new bug that comes on to the list as it happens. They should put a severity rating on each (coloured sticky dot, tag in Trello) so the product owner can make an informed decision about it's priority based on the impact to the product.
- Every week/sprint/cycle, commit to some fixed number of bugs from the list. Make the product owner, scrum master, tech lead or manager of the team enforce this rutual.
- Ensure the team or those working on said bugs are given sufficient time and space to "squash" (fix) them.